# Novice website creator. Cannot get forms to work with php script

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I've created a website and I have no business working in php. The website is up and running, but the form is not working correctly. Right now it submits to my sform.php file, but just shows a blank page and does not submit to the email in the $to portion (which I replaced with redacted@redacted.com for privacy reasons). Here is the form code along with the php. I'm sure you all will know exactly what the issue is right away. Sorry for my ignorance.

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="sform.php">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone" class="col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="company" class="col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <input type="company" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company Name">
                        </div>
                      </div>


    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
    <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="What can we do for you?"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>  Submit</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                   </form><!-- form -->
```

=========================================================

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['comments'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'redacted'; 
    $to = 'redacted@redacted.com'; 
    $subject = 'redacted ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Comments: $comments\n";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['comments']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }
    //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
    if ($human !== 5) {
        $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
    }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will be in contact with you shortly.</div>';
} else {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again.</div>';
}
}
}
?>
```

==================================================================

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Did you make sure the variables used in the `mail` function are all correct? Perhaps `echo` them to see.

Comment: How would I echo this out?

Comment: @JHall your main big problem is that all your form elements does not have name attribute

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Sorry; you know how things are/can get around here ;-) and how they don't usually don't know what to do with tools out there to help them catch the errors. It's been asked too many times and not researched enough.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no worries I was making the answer a community wiki so didn't lose anything

Comment: I would simply have my PHP file be one line of code to see if the variables are being passed correctly. 
`echo $_POST['name'];`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed out name attribute in text box.
Your code :

```
<input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
```

Try this :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
```

And in all input fields do add name="something".

Answer (score -1):

Your $err* variables are only set if the POST value is not set, but you test them anyway. They don't exist if the POST values are set. By changing things around a bit, you might approach it like:

```
if (!$_POST['comments']) {
    $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
} else {
    $errMessage = false;
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
}
```

This may not be the best approach as such, but you can probably get this working and then improve it as your skills progress.